# Drag and Drop of Data in InfoPath

Tags: wpf, list, drag-and-drop, treeview, infopath

I'm trying to avoid rolling my own form using .NET and WPF or WinForms and i'm wondering if it is possible to use **InfoPath**.

The goal is to either be able to drag items from one list (possibly using a multiselect) in to another list of lists. Or, alternatively I would like to drag items in a tree view (or repeating table - the apparently nearest thing in InfoPath).

Drag and drop is definitely preferable to having buttons that push things between lists.  I have played with WPF and it's a lot of work!  Is there a way in InfoPath?

N.B. To be clear I am not asking about using drag and drop during the *design* of the InfoPath form but using it for data manipulation in the published form.

Comment: Just as a note: InfoPath has been discontinued following Office 2013.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative technology?